# Better method to drill through array than nested loop?

Tags: php, drupal

I have a menu structure (Drupal) that contains elements representing a menu link. If the menu has a child menu (is the parent of a submenu) it has an array key 'below' with a menu item inside with the same structure. In theory this menu could be infinitely deep and the only way that I know how to go through each level is by create a new loop on the item if 'below' has anything in it. I know there has to be a more elegant and dynamic way to deal with this. I'm not really looking for a Drupal specific answer as this problem has come up before and I've just hacked it together. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Have you tried array recursion? In the absence of a hint as to what you're attempting to do, you can read about `array_replace_recursive()` and `array_walk_recursive()`

Comment: array_walk() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php next() http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example of the kind of data you're working with it's difficult to give an exact implementation, but the general class of problems you describe is one that can usually be solved with recursion - a function that calls itself.

```
<?php
function deepPrintArr (array $arr)
{
    $output = '';
    foreach ($arr as $elem)
    {
        if (is_array $elem)
        {
            $output .= deepPrintArr ($elem);
        }
        else
        {
            $output .= "<p>$elem</p>\n";
        }
    }
    return ($output);
}

echo (deepPrintArr ($some_deeply_nested_array));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take time to "read" /inc/menu.inc in your drupal code.
This file contains a host of very usefull functions, some are not mentioned in any documentation.
menu_get_active_trail() for example gives you the current active path for the active page. This is a lot easier than looping recursive through all menu items in your own code.

For this site: [Qrios](http://www.qrios.nl) I wrote some code to build a two level menu in Drupal:

```
   <?php $base_tree = menu_tree_page_data($use_menu);
    //Debug
    //print_r($tree);
    foreach ($base_tree as $item) {
      if ($item['link']['in_active_trail'] == 1){
        $tree = $item['below'];
      }else{
        $tree = array(); //empty array
      }
    } ?>
```

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you get the idea of using Drupals functions. You just have to find them.